# Finding Duplicate string values in two cell array 22124x1

Tags: matlab

I have a cell 22124x1 and it contain duplicate Values, I want to know how many times these values duplicate and their index

first cell contain these values Datacell=

```
  '221853_s_at'
  '221971_x_at'
  '221971_x_at'
  '221971_x_at'
  '221971_x_at'
  '222031_at'
  '222031_at'
  '31637_s_at'
  '37796_at'
  '38340_at'
```

symbol cell:

```
 'OR1D4 '
  ' OR1D5'
   ' UTP14C'
    'GTF2H2 '
   'ZNF324B '
  ' LOC644504'
   'JMJD7 '
  'ZNF324B '
  'JMJD7-PLA2G4B'
  ' OR2A5 '
   'OR1D4 '
```

For example i want the output from cell 1 like this

```
ID               duplicated       index
'221853_s_at'       1               1
'221971_x_at'       4             {2:5,1}
```

I tried to use unique but it does not work. Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Can you reduce your example inputs please and add a hand worked desired example output

Comment: How is "symbol cell" related to your question? Do you want to find duplicates in there as well?

Comment: Your example output does not make sense. `'221853_s_at'` is not duplicated in the data provided. Do you want a count of occurrences of *all* strings or just the duplicated ones? How are you defining `duplicated`? Is it the total count of the string in the array or `total count - 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating the indices in a visually pleasing matter isn't necessarily a trivial exercise. It's made simpler if you assume `d` is sorted.

An alternative utilizing `accumarray`:

```
d = {'221853_s_at'; '221971_x_at'; '221971_x_at';  '221971_x_at'; '221971_x_at'; ...
     '222031_at'; '222031_at'; '31637_s_at'; '37796_at'; '38340_at' ...
     };
d = sort(d); % Sort to make indices easier

% Find unique strings and their locations
[uniquestrings, ~, stringbin] = unique(d);
counts = accumarray(stringbin, 1);

repeatidx = find(counts - 1 > 0);
repeatedstrings = uniquestrings(repeatidx);
repeatcounts = counts(repeatidx) - 1;

% Find where string repeats start
startidx = find([true; diff(stringbin) > 0]);
repeatstart = startidx(repeatidx);
repeatend = startidx(repeatidx + 1) - 1;

% Generate table, requires R2013b or newer
t = table(repeatedstrings, repeatcounts, repeatstart, repeatend, ...
          'VariableNames', {'ID', 'Duplicated', 'StringStart', 'StringEnd'} ...
          );
```

Which yields:

```
t = 

         ID          Duplicated    StringStart    StringEnd
    _____________    __________    ___________    _________

    '221971_x_at'    3             2              5        
    '222031_at'      1             6              7
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {  '221853_s_at'
  '221971_x_at'
  '221971_x_at'
  '221971_x_at'
  '221971_x_at'
  '222031_at'
  '222031_at'
  '31637_s_at'
  '37796_at'
  '38340_at'};

[ids,ia,ic]=unique(d);
```

ids has the unique strings
ia has an index corresponding to an instance of the unique string within d
ic has an index corresponding to which entry in ids is in that index within d

```
[ncnt] = hist(ic,1:numel(ids)) - 1; % minus 1 since you only want duplicates

ncnt =

     0     3     1     0     0     0
```

Gets you the number of duplicates for
ids =

```
'221853_s_at'
'221971_x_at'
'222031_at'
'31637_s_at'
'37796_at'
'38340_at'
```

ic has the lookup table for the indexes.. use find or logical indexing

Comment: Thx @haindbaii  but it is working for just short column I have 22124x1